# Observe Live Data After Second Live Data

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-livedata

My view Model 
declares two live data   :

the scenario is getting two methods from the repository so that second live data input arguments  dependent on first live data got data

```
public class ProductViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

private LiveData<DataWrapper<GetProductQuery.Product>> productLiveData;
private LiveData<DataWrapper<ArrayList<ProductList>>> vendorProductLiveData;


private ProductRepository repository ;

public ProductViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
    super(application);
    repository = new ProductRepository();

}

public LiveData<DataWrapper<GetProductQuery.Product>> getProductLiveData(String productId) {
    productLiveData = repository.getProduct(productId);
    return productLiveData;
}

public LiveData<DataWrapper<ArrayList<ProductList>>> getVendorProductLiveData(int vendorId) {
    vendorProductLiveData = repository.getLimitProduct(vendorId);
    return vendorProductLiveData;
} }
```

in Activity i want run second live data after first live data :

```
viewModel.getVendorProductLiveData(Integer.parseInt(p.getId())).observe(getActivity(), arrayListDataWrapper -> {

                ArrayList<ProductList> pList = 
  arrayListDataWrapper.getData();
 });



viewModel.getProductLiveData(id).observe(this, productDataWrapper -> {
                p = productDataWrapper.getData();
});



                viewModel.getVendorProductLiveData(Integer.parseInt(p.getId())).observe(getActivity(), arrayListDataWrapper -> {
//do logic after get product

});
```

Comment: see [this](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata#transform_livedata) and [this](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata#create_new_transformations) (and [this](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata#merge_livedata) too could be useful)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Transformations.switchMap()` to transform your first `LiveData` to your second `LiveData` using the former emitted value as the argument. Then you can observe this transformed `LiveData` to get the final result.